# Bus emits event too many times [Updated desc.]

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Ive got the following problem:

I got 2 components which are passing data to each other via the bus.
In my case I'm looking for the portfolio_id in the ViewCustomer Component and send it to the AddPortfolioFund Component. In addition to the ID im passing a variable that sets the dialog in the AddPortfolioFund to true.

I get the right ID and emit it here together with the variable to show the dialog

```
createPortfolioFund({ portfolio_id }) {
  this.selectedPortfolio = portfolio_id
  bus.$emit("ViewAddPortfolioFund", (this.addPortfolioFund = true)); //Variable to show the Dialog
  bus.$emit("getSelectedPortfolio", this.selectedPortfolio); //Here im sending it
  bus.$emit("buyFundForCustomer", this.editedItem.customer_id);
},
```

In the AddPortfolioFund component I show the dialog by getting the emited variable and access the ID for working with it.

And at this point i'm having trouble, cause the AddPortfolioFund component get's opend as often es ID's exist in the array from portfolios

When I click the button in ViewCustomer.vue with createPortfolioFund() function, it gets the ID from the clicked Object and after that I want to pass that ID and a variable via bus to show the dialog.
In the AddPortfolioFund Component I firstly want to display the dialog and after that work with the passed ID

ViewCustomer.vue

```js
import { bus } from "../../main";
import axios from "axios";
import AddPortfolioFundComponent from "./AddPortfolioFund.vue";
import SellPortfolioFundComponent from "./SellPortfolioFund.vue";


export default {
  components: {
    AddPortfolioFundComponent,
    SellPortfolioFundComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      viewCustomer: false,
      editedItem: {},
      portfolios: [],
      userdata: {},
      ConfirmAddPortfolio: false,
      selectedPortfolio: {},
      dialogNote: {},
      selectedPortfolio2: {}
    };
  },

  methods: {
    
    createPortfolioFund({ portfolio_id }) {
      this.selectedPortfolio = portfolio_id
      bus.$emit("ViewAddPortfolioFund", (this.addPortfolioFund = true));
      bus.$emit("getSelectedPortfolio", this.selectedPortfolio);
      bus.$emit("buyFundForCustomer", this.editedItem.customer_id);
    },

  created() {
    bus.$on("viewCustomer", data => {
      this.viewCustomer = data;
    });
    bus.$on("EditData", editData => {
      this.editedItem = editData;
    });
    bus.$on("UserDataChannel", userData => {
      this.userdata = userData;
    });
  }
};
```

```html
                <v-card-text v-for="(item, index) in portfolios" :key="index">
                  <v-card
                    dark
                    color="gradient"
                    elevation="4"
                    class="pa-2 ml-auto mr-auto justify-center"
                    max-width="1000px"
                  >
                    <v-list-item three-line>
                      <v-list-item-content color="red">
                        <div class="overline mb-2">
                          <v-chip color="white" light x-small>Depot-Nr: {{item.portfolio_id}}</v-chip>
                        </div>
                        <v-list-item-title
                          class="display-1 mb-1"
                        >{{formatPrice(item.portfolio_value)}}€</v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-subtitle>
                          Einstandwert: {{formatPrice(item.investment_capital)}}€
                          <br />
                        </v-list-item-subtitle>
                      </v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-avatar size="80" color="#fff">
                        <v-icon color="#243B55" large>mdi-bank</v-icon>
                      </v-list-item-avatar>
                    </v-list-item>
                    <template v-if="!item.funds.length"></template>
                    <template v-else>
                      <v-simple-table class="ml-4 mr-4" light>
                        <template v-slot:default>
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="text-left">ISIN</th>
                              <th class="text-left">Name</th>
                              <th class="text-left">Stückzahl</th>
                              <th class="text-left">Marktpreis</th>
                              <th class="text-left">Positionswert</th>
                              <th class="text-left mr-2">Kaufpreis</th>
                              <th class="text-left">Performance</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="(items,index) in item.funds" :key="index">
                              <td>{{items.isin}}</td>
                              <td class="font-weight-bold">{{items.fund_name}}</td>
                              <td>{{items.quantity}}</td>
                              <td>{{items.marketprice}} €</td>
                              <td>{{items.positionswert}} €</td>
                              <td>{{items.buying_price}} €</td>
                              <td>{{items.performance}} %</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </template>
                      </v-simple-table>
                    </template>
                   <AddPortfolioFundComponent></AddPortfolioFundComponent>
                    <SellPortfolioFundComponent></SellPortfolioFundComponent>
                    <v-list-item-action>
                      <v-layout row class="ml-auto">
                        <v-btn
                          elevation="0"
                          dark
                          color="green"
                          small
                          class="mr-4"
                          @click.once="createPortfolioFund(item)"
                        >
                          <v-icon left small>mdi-plus</v-icon>Kaufen
                        </v-btn>
                        <template v-if="!item.funds.length"></template>
                        <template v-else>
                          <v-btn
                            elevation="0"
                            dark
                            color="red"
                            small
                            v-model="selectedPortfolio2"
                            @click="sellPortFund(item)"
                          >
                            <v-icon left small>mdi-minus</v-icon>Verkaufen
                          </v-btn>
                        </template>
                      </v-layout>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                  </v-card>
                </v-card-text>
              </div>
            </template>
          </div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
```

AddPortfolioFund.vue

```js
import { bus } from "../../main";
import axios from "axios";

  created() {
    bus.$on("ViewAddPortfolioFund", data1 => {
      this.addPortfolioFund = data1;
      console.log(data1)
    });
    bus.$on("getSelectedPortfolio", data => {
      this.selectedPortfolio = data;
    });
    bus.$on("buyFundForCustomer", editData => {
      this.editedItem = editData;
    });
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initialize();
  },
 
  methods: {
    
    formatPrice(value) {
      let val = (value / 1).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
      return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    },
   
    buyFund() {
      let addFundToPortfolio = {
        portfolio_id: this.selectedPortfolio.portfolio_id,
        fund_id: this.getSelectedFund.fund_id,
        quantity: this.quantity,
        buying_price: this.getSelectedFund.marketprice
      };
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/customer/addFund", addFundToPortfolio)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          bus.$emit('portfolio-updated')
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            alert("Sie können pro Depot in maximal 3 Fonds investieren.")
          } 
        });
        this.addPortfolioFund = false;  
        this.actualStep = 1;
        this.selectedPortfolio.portfolio_id = null;
        this.getSelectedFund.fund_id = null;
        this.quantity = null;
        this.getSelectedFund.marketprice = null;
        this.updateIt;
    }
  }
};
```

```
[
{
    "portfolio_id": 7,
    "funds": [
        {
            "fund_id": 1,
            "fund_inventory_id": 8,
            "isin": "DE000DK0ECK6",
            "fund_name": "LION-GlobalChampions",
            "quantity": 87,
            "marketprice": "247.73",
            "positionswert": "21552.51",
            "performance": "4.00",
            "buying_price": "238.20"
        }
    ],
    "investment_capital": "20723.40",
    "portfolio_value": "21552.51"
},
{
    "portfolio_id": 16,
    "funds": [],
    "investment_capital": "0.00",
    "portfolio_value": "0.00"
},
{
    "portfolio_id": 22,
    "funds": [],
    "investment_capital": "0.00",
    "portfolio_value": "0.00"
},
{
    "portfolio_id": 80,
    "funds": [],
    "investment_capital": "0.00",
    "portfolio_value": "0.00"
},
{
    "portfolio_id": 81,
    "funds": [],
    "investment_capital": "0.00",
    "portfolio_value": "0.00"
}
```

]

Comment: I didn't get your question. can you append that what are you getting and what are you expecting to get in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand.

```
@click="createPortfolioFund(item)"
```

and

```
@click="sellPortFund(item)"
```

Will have the `methods` sellPortFund and createPortfolioFund access to the `item`. Remember that this is a reference not a unique object.

Have you tried this? createPortfolioFund({portfolio_id})

What does the v-btn have a v-model property for? I removed it in the file below. When you click on the buttons the id is logged to the console.

Hope this helps.

```
<template>
  <div class="justify-center">
    <v-card-text v-for="(item, index) in portfolios" :key="index">
      <v-card
        dark
        color="gradient"
        elevation="4"
        class="pa-2 ml-auto mr-auto justify-center"
        max-width="1000px"
      >
        <v-list-item three-line>
          <v-list-item-content color="red">
            <div class="overline mb-2">
              <v-chip color="white" light x-small>Depot-Nr: {{ item.portfolio_id }}</v-chip>
            </div>
            <v-list-item-title class="display-1 mb-1">{{ formatPrice(item.portfolio_value) }}€</v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>
              Einstandwert: {{ formatPrice(item.investment_capital) }}€
              <br />
            </v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-avatar size="80" color="#fff">
            <v-icon color="#243B55" large>mdi-bank</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
        </v-list-item>
        <template v-if="!item.funds.length"></template>
        <template v-else>
          <v-simple-table class="ml-4 mr-4" light>
            <template v-slot:default>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-left">ISIN</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Name</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Stückzahl</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Marktpreis</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Positionswert</th>
                  <th class="text-left mr-2">Kaufpreis</th>
                  <th class="text-left">Performance</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(items, index) in item.funds" :key="index">
                  <td>{{ items.isin }}</td>
                  <td class="font-weight-bold">{{ items.fund_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ items.quantity }}</td>
                  <td>{{ items.marketprice }} €</td>
                  <td>{{ items.positionswert }} €</td>
                  <td>{{ items.buying_price }} €</td>
                  <td>{{ items.performance }} %</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </template>
          </v-simple-table>
        </template>
        <v-list-item-action>
          <v-layout row class="ml-auto">
            <v-btn
              elevation="0"
              dark
              color="green"
              small
              class="mr-4"
              @click="createPortfolioFund(item)"
            >
              <v-icon left small>mdi-plus</v-icon>Kaufen
            </v-btn>
            <template v-if="!item.funds.length"></template>
            <template v-else>
              <v-btn elevation="0" dark color="red" small @click="sellPortFund(item)">
                <v-icon left small>mdi-minus</v-icon>Verkaufen
              </v-btn>
            </template>
          </v-layout>
        </v-list-item-action>
      </v-card>
    </v-card-text>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    sellPortFund({ portfolio_id }: any): void {
      console.log(portfolio_id);
    },
    createPortfolioFund({ portfolio_id }: any): void {
      console.log(portfolio_id);
    },
    formatPrice() {
      return "xxx";
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    portfolios: [
      {
        portfolio_id: 7,
        funds: [
          {
            fund_id: 1,
            fund_inventory_id: 8,
            isin: "DE000DK0ECK6",
            fund_name: "LION-GlobalChampions",
            quantity: 87,
            marketprice: "247.73",
            positionswert: "21552.51",
            performance: "4.00",
            buying_price: "238.20"
          }
        ],
        investment_capital: "20723.40",
        portfolio_value: "21552.51"
      },
      {
        portfolio_id: 16,
        funds: [],
        investment_capital: "0.00",
        portfolio_value: "0.00"
      },
      {
        portfolio_id: 22,
        funds: [],
        investment_capital: "0.00",
        portfolio_value: "0.00"
      },
      {
        portfolio_id: 80,
        funds: [],
        investment_capital: "0.00",
        portfolio_value: "0.00"
      },
      {
        portfolio_id: 81,
        funds: [],
        investment_capital: "0.00",
        portfolio_value: "0.00"
      }
    ]
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for trying to help me! :) Well it didn't solve my problem, as i'm already passing the right ID. The only problem is that when I emit it, it gets as often emited as ID's exist in the array. Normally it should just open a single dialog in AddPortfolioFund but it opens the dialog several times